# C++ code conflicts with Antivirus/VPN and freezes/crashes computer

Tags: mpi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openmpi, antivirus, symantec

I've written a code that utilizes OpenMPI for a message passing interface. However, when I run the code, it freezes everything on my computer except for my mouse and the only fix is a forced restart or a shut down.

I'm running the code from WSL and when I don't have my antivirus (Symantec Endpoint Protection) on, it will run just fine. The issue is, I need SEP to get onto the VPN I need for work.

I've tried running WSL as an admin and I'd try using other antivirus but SEP is the one I need for the VPN. Is this a common issue with MPI? Is there a way I can work around this without having to disable my firewall everytime I want to run the code?

I apologize if this is to vague and will gladly post any other information that may be useful. I'm just not sure what may be useful for right now.

Comment: try running something trivial such as `mpirun hostname`. If that freezes, you might have to whitelist `mpirun`.

Comment: Please remove the "openmp" tag on this. OpenMPI != OpenMP, and you have nothing OpenMP relevant here.

Comment: @JimCownie Fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet It appears the hostname worked just fine. What would this indicate is causing an issue?

Comment: What if you start a single MPI task (e.g. `mpirun -np 1 a.out` ?

Comment: That is when the issue shows. I can run a code just like that. I won't get any feedback from the executable. Then my windows machine starts to freeze. I can't close anything, I am able to restart the computer but it takes a long time. And it only occurs when I have the antivirus on. If I was on a pure linux it would be simple enough to whitelist the software but I'm not sure with the Windows Subsystem.